# What is the difference between "could not get to" and "did not get to"?

Tags: word-choice, differences, meaning-in-context

Take, for example, this sentence:

> Away from Vatican City, Tome was quiet as authorities ordered all public offices and schools to close (*close*), and banned (*ban*) cars from the roads. Millions of Catholics who ______________ (*not get*) to Italy, bid (*bid*) him farewell in myriad services round the globe.

What's the grammatically correct form of the concept "to not get" in this context, to fill in the blank and complete the sentence?

The word must be derived from "get", or the phrase include "get", in order to be consistent with the pattern that that the words/phrases preceding bracketed words are derivations of those bracketed words.

Comment: Probably *could not*, but could easily be *did not*. Either would be grammatically correct, and the difference would come down to the particular shade of meaning the author desired to express.

Comment: "Millions of Catholics who *were unable to get to* Italy" also fits.

Comment: 'Could not get to Italy' suggests that they were not able to go to Italy for some reason. 'Didn't get to Italy' suggests they just didn't go, but not necessarily that they  intended to go.

Comment: Thanks for clearing my doubt Robusto and Josh61. Mari-Lou A I have a question for you. Upon discussing the answers of Robusto and Josh61 with my friend he agreed that using "could not" is more appropriate in this scenario because of the reasons as mentioned by both of them, but he told me not to use "unable to" as it was not a modal verb. So, could you please shed light on this? When I asked him the reason behind it, he explained in a manner which was not understood by me!

Comment: "Could not" means that there was some reason why the activity was not possible.  "Did not" means that either the people "could not", or for some other reason they chose to not undertake the activity.

Comment: Thanks Hot Licks,Mari Lou A and Josh61 for clearing my concept!

Comment: Frankly, the question is not entirely clear. I see there are unrelated ideas in the question(s).

Comment: Just replace 'get to' by 'reach': 'could/did not reach'. What is the problem? This is very basic.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth the exercise requires that the verb "get" is used. To answer Ranajoy Saha's question; if I say *I can get to work*, it can mean one of two things **1)** It is "possible" for me to get there **2)** I am "capable" of getting there (I have the ability). The verb [to able to](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/be_able_to) expresses ability. So, *I am able to get to work* is the same meaning as 2).

Comment: For tye benefit of @Mari-Lou A: Just see how replacing 'get to' with 'reach' makes the question simpler. Answer this question, and the corresponding question becomes clear. But thank you for pointing out that this is homework. Oh, and if we're being pedantic, _unable to get_ doesn't fulfil the homework's "to not get" requirement. Or are there different rules for different posters?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I didn't say it did, I said it also fitted, as an alternative answer. I never said your solution was incorrect. But you asked "What is the problem?" and I gave you an answer. I didn't mean to sound rude.

Comment: And I'm pointing out that (1) the basic question here seems to be differentiating between 'could not' and 'did not' and (2) as such this isn't ELU material.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is similar to that of can and may. Saying to someone "Sorry, I could not get to that" is like saying "I can't get to it because I am physically or mentally unable to." If you "Did not get to that" it means you most likely can, just were busy in the mean time with no time to do said task. "I'm sorry, I did not get to that. I'll do it right now."

I hope this answers your question!

Answer (score -1):

Comments by [Josh61](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/230706/what-is-the-difference-between-could-not-get-to-and-did-not-get-to#comment493899_230706) notwithstanding, *to get to X* normally implies *to reach a **target** [location, situation, condition]*. This implication is even stronger in *negated* constructions, where *to **not** get to X* strongly implies there was a ***failed attempt*** to reach X. Consider...

> 1: *I **did not get** to the party last night*
>    2: *I **did not make it** to the party last night*
>    3: *I **did not go** to the party last night*

...where #1 and #2 are largely equivalent (I wanted and/or made some attempt to attend the party, but for some reason I wasn't able to be there). #3 carries no such implications, which illustrates a clear distinction between ***get*** and ***go*** in such constructions.

---

Therefore, although *in general* there's a difference between ***did not*** ("neutral", implying nothing about desirability or possibility) and ***could not*** ("loaded", implying being *prevented* from doing something, usually *desirable*), in OP's specific context there's really little to choose between the two, because of the way ***to get to X*** is normally understood.

Comment: I see significant difference. Maybe it's just me.

Comment: @Kris: Are you seriously saying you don't see much difference between *"We didn't **get** to the funeral"* (we'd have liked to, but it wasn't possible) and *"We didn't **go** to the funeral"* (perhaps because we never wanted to be there anyway)?

Comment: I **do** see a difference, did I say I don't? :)

Comment: @Kris: I assume you meant you *do* see a difference between ***did not*** and ***could not***. My entire argument here is based on the premise that *to **get to** X* (as opposed to *to **go to** X*) already implies a "desire" to end up at X, particularly in *negated* contexts. Therefore to my mind it makes no real difference whether OP explicitly reinforces the "frustrated desire" element using ***could***, since it's effectively just repeating the implication already made by choosing to use ***get to*** rather than ***go to***.